# Who built the Wayne?

Tags: welcome-to-the-wayne

In the TV Show 'Welcome To The Wayne', who built the Wayne?

Even if we dont have the exact identity, is it ever alluded to in the course of the show?

Comment: It would appear that we don't know from google/the wikia, though I don't know anything about this show.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I know. I also Googled it. That's why I asked here.

Comment: I watched the show, and cannot recall anyone ever giving the backstory of the building. I would strongly suspect, given the nature of the structure, it was the Satanic equivalent of the Lovecraftian cult who constructed the apartment block featured in the first sexist GHOSTBUSTERS film.